# How to make ranks in MCPE 1.13

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I’m an owner of a Minecraft Factions Realm and would like to create ranks, such as default, lord, owner, etc. After watching millions of tutorial videos I still cannot find a way to have prefixes in chat. How do I do this? Thanks.

Comment: So these ranks change your "prefix" in chat? Also, how do you gain these ranks? Please add more information in your question.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think those are done with Plugins and not commands. And I also don't think you can use plugins on realms.

Comment: @cherryblossom Sorry about that. You can only obtain ranks through the OP. And yes they change your prefix in chat. I’ve seen people do this, actually, without using plugins.